Function to convert logic vector into string
I wrote this function to convert a logic vector into string bit by bit:
module top_2;

  function automatic string logic_to_string(logic vec []);
    string str;
    for (int i=0; i<$size(vec); i++) begin
      str = {str, (vec[i] === 1'bx) ? "x" : (vec[i] === 1'bz) ? "z" : (vec[i] ? "1" : "0")};
    end
    return str;
  endfunction

   initial begin
    logic [3:0] x;
        x = "1010";
        #1;
    $display(logic_to_string(x));
   end 

endmodule

I do not understand why I keep getting result as all zeros. What is wrong with this program? If I use (logic [] vec) instead, it does not compile.
I tried these two and they don't compile as well:
  function automatic string logic_to_string(logic vec []);
    return $sformatf("%b", vec);
  endfunction
** Error (suppressible): (vlog-2997)
top_2.sv(20): Arg. 'vec' of 'logic_to_string':  Cannot assign a packed type 'reg[3:0]' to an unpacked type 'reg $[]'

and this
  function automatic string logic_to_string(logic [] vec);
    return $sformatf("%b", vec);
  endfunction

top_2.sv(12): (vlog-13169) Packed dimension must specify a range.

At the end, I tried this one:
   initial begin
    logic [3:0] x;
    logic str;
        x = "1010";
    str = $sformatf("%b", x);
        #1;
    $display(str);
   end 
Error (suppressible): (vsim-7041)    
top_2.sv(16): String assignment:  Assigning a string to a packed type requires a cast.


I don't think you need to create your own function for that.  You can use $sformatf with %b:
module top_2;
    initial begin
        logic [3:0] x;
        string str;
        x = 10    ; str = $sformatf("%b", x); $display("%s", str);
        x = '1    ; str = $sformatf("%b", x); $display("%s", str);
        x = 'b1zx0; str = $sformatf("%b", x); $display("%s", str);
    end 
endmodule

Prints:
1010
1111
1zx0


You have two issues. First, assigning that string to the logic array isn't doing what you want. (VHDL has some types that treat logic values like strings, but SystemVerilog doesn't do that. Doing that in SV will give you a truncated version of the binary encoding of the string.) Second, you need to convert the packed array to unpacked for the function call.
Try this:
initial begin
    logic [3:0] x;
    x = 'b1010;
    #1;
    $display(logic_to_string({>>{x}}));
end 


Packed vs Unpacked?  The function is supposed to take in a logic vector and then iterate over it. How does this bring packed vs unpacked into the story? I really don't know what packed vs unpacked is and will have a look. In VHDL I can just write std_logic_vector in the parameter and the function will work.
